# Firefox won't store cookie when page is loaded within an iframe

Tags: firefox, cookies, iframe, setcookie

I have a parent webpage with a child iframe:

- parent at `https://first-site.com`
- child at `<iframe src="https://second-site.com">` (inside of parent)
- cookie is set by the `second-site.com` server upon page load using this HTTP header:

  - `Set-Cookie: iqsession=869194b8e575d0d333f9395557f564f5eca31c15761c; expires=Wed, 08-Feb-2023 03:51:14 GMT; Max-Age=600; path=/; secure; httponly; samesite=none`
- When I load the page on `first-site.com` (with `second-site.com` in an iframe), Firefox fails to store the cookie for `second-site.com`. It's not accessible under the cookies tab, nor is it available to `second-site.com` on subsequent page loads. There are no warnings or errors in the console.
- This *does* work in Chrome.
- Note that I am **not** attempting to access cookies across domains.  The cookie is only set by `second-site.com` on the server side and only read by `second-site.com` on the server side. The outer parent doesn't need to know anything about the cookie.

Any ideas why this isn't working in Firefox?  [This issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1653188) looks related but isn't super clear.

Comment: Have you found a solution by now? I'm experiencing a similar issue. When firefox has stored cookies for second-site.com, these cookies won't be sent when second-site.com is embedded via iframe

Comment: I solved it by breaking out of the iframe, so that my second-site.com was the `_top` frame, checking for the cookie, and then reloading the original page.  I was able to break out of the iframe because I am using Shopify App Bridge, which opens up sort of a backchannel control interface between the embedded frame and the containing site. I'm using the cookies in an auth flow.

Comment: P.S.  I came to the conclusion that it's impossible to make the cookies work in Firefox while they're inside an iframe.  That's just my conclusion.  YMMV.

Comment: FF seems to ignore the SameSite=None at default security setting (which is against what SameSite=None is).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the exact same problem that you describe.

However, after struggling with it for a while, I discovered that **in my case it was only happening because I was using a self-signed certificate that Firefox didn't recognize as valid**. When testing the exact same code in an environment with a proper certificate, everything worked as expected.